# How do I create a draggable page (map) for a large image with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xhtml, css, prototypejs

I would like to recreate a page like this: http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de **but in jQuery**. Are there any jQuery plugins out there that do this? (The above link is written using prototype).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the guy who made the IRRLAND map. It's written using Prototype, indeed. I did a similar project a couple of weeks ago; it's actually based on the IRRLAND map engine, but completely re-written using jQuery. Maybe you want to have a look at it and try to rebuild it yourself.

http://www.rocknrollmetromap.com/

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Love this! Would be very cool to get the drag & drop to work on mobile, too. Do you think that would require a lot of effort to implement on top of your plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery scrollTo and some css trickery (probably overflow:hidden) this should do the trick: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 1):

The page in your example has some really nice animations. You will probably need to add those 'nice' effects yourself but there are a couple of jQuery plugins you can try:

1. https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki/
2. http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/

UPDATE:

Also check this out:

1. http://www.gethifi.com/blog/jquery-vs-flash-for-interactive-map
2. http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/03/10-jquery-plugins-for-easier-google-map-installation/
3. http://www.ajaxupdates.com/mapbox-zoomable-jquery-map-plugin/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be very hard to implement using jQueryUI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). The draggable must be inside a container (widht: 100%, height: 100%, overflow: hidden). Draggable has various options and events. On `stop` for example you should check if the dragged object is away from the container edges and slide it back to them.